# WordPress mod_rewrite query strings returning 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect below url

```
http://192.168.1.47/web_sufalamtech/case-studies.htm?id=real-estate
```

to

```
http://192.168.1.47/web_sufalamtech/case-studies.htm/real-estate
```

I have used this code

```
function init_custom_rewrite() {
add_rewrite_rule( 
    '^case-studies/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    '?page_id=108&id=$matches[1]',        
    'top' 
);}


add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars', 10, 1);
function my_query_vars($vars) {$vars[] = 'id';$vars[] = 'n';return $vars;}
```

It is giving me 404 error.

Comment: The pattern you specified there would match something of the form `case-studies/…/…` - neither of those two URLs you have shown matches that format to begin with.

Comment: It should be helpfull can you try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478152/change-url-with-get-parameters-to-url-with-path-wordpress-site/59484375#59484375